# why VScode does not recognize pynput mouse.position?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pynput, pylance

im beginner in python programming and i start learning it with visual studio IDE there something wrong with it when i use the below code to get mouse current position it will work fine but mouse.position is not in autocomplete list.

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller

mouse = Controller()

# Read pointer position
print('The current pointer position is {0}'.format(mouse.position))
```

also i tried reinstall all include: VS Code, python,pip but still i have the issue.
im using pylance and python extension in VS Code.

please have a look at the screenshot i got for better understanding of my question:

https://pasteboard.co/JYHc2Vy.png

thanks for any advice.

Comment: It's not surprising that VS Code can't tell what methods the `pynput` classes have - there are multiple implementations of each class, one for each supported platform, that are dynamically chosen when the module is imported.  VS Code wouldn't know which one to use for autocompletion.

Comment: yes, it seems to be right but how can i fix this issue?
i have this issue with win32api too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of hours searching i found out there is something wrong(Maybe Bug or something) with pylance extension in VS Code after remove it from the VS and revert to Jedi the issue gone!